# How do you acquire a Power BI token in C#

Tags: c#, powerbi, access-token

I am trying to get an access token to leverage the Power BI API stack but the only documentation I've been able to acquire is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/automation/walkthrough-push-data-get-token) coming from Microsoft. The last update for the doc according to the page reflects 5/19/2019 so it's not that old and there are no redirect links to indicate newer code.

When I write the following code:

```
 var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri)).Result.AccessToken;
```

I receive 2 errors within VS2019 regarding the 2nd and 3rd arguments:

**Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential'**
**Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Uri' to 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserAssertion'**

I am running code on .NET 5 Core but have also tried running on the .NET Framework with the same result so I don't believe it is Framework specific; and can't understand why the white paper hasn't been updated if this method isn't any longer supported.

How can I acquire a token for the API calls? Are there docs for a newer implementation available somewhere?

Comment: have a look other ways of getting token https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/get-azuread-access-token, beside the version which you using is deprecated https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.21.301221612

Comment: Thanks @coder_b!